# Organize Finder Sidebar

Tags: macos, finder

Is there any kind of application (I don't mind paying) which offers more advanced editing/organization of the Finder sidebar, more specifically the "Places" section.

I would really like to be able to group things into sub groups and/or color them.

Any help making this more useful would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about external apps, and I don't think you can use colors, at least not the normal label colors.

However, what I do is in my home folder, I have a folder called "SideBar folders" and in there, I have a bunch of folders that have aliases to other things, like various project folders, and apps, etc... then I put the folders of aliases into my sidebar.

This is particularly useful because i have a bunch of things (php code sets, for example) that exist, in slight variation on 4 different computers, so I can have folders mine, Chris's, etc with links in them with pretty much all the same names, but one goes to my copy of the database, and one goes to Chris's... n

Comment: When you click on the folder from the sidebar, does it expand out (like the taskbar) or just open the folder up in a finder window?

Comment: It just opens the folder in the finder window...

Answer (score 0):

[Sidebar Separators](http://www.typoet.com/separators/index.html) is a workaround to get separated sections in the sidebar.